# Unable to enter EFI firmware

Tags: windows-8.1, bios, uefi, lenovo-laptop, ubuntu-15.04

I have Lenovo (G580 Model 20157) laptop. It had Windows 8.1. I dual booted it with Ubuntu 15.04. I am unable to go into EFI setup since then. I tried that by:

- Pressing F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, Del and Esc keys.
- By using Novo button.
- From windows 8.1 Update and recovery options.
- By turning of fast start up option and hibernate option in power options.
- Using Shift key while shutting down for complete shut down.
- List item

But it didn't work. When I pressed Esc key it says "System bios shadowed Video BIOS shadowed"

I tried to find the firmware update for Windows 8.1 but I didn't find it. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Did the Novo button restarts your PC ?

Comment: Yes. It restarts my PC.

Comment: Normally, the button should restart your PC directly into the repair mode. From this you can access the UEFI and perform some maintenance tasks.